# How can I pass a URL filter to publish to a web report?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

How can I pass a parameter through "publish to web" URL in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Query string filtering doesn't work with publish to web or Export to PDF.

References:

*[Considerations and troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#considerations-and-troubleshooting)*